# PHP Contact Form - How many else if are you allowed?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form

I'm sure this has been asked if it has please point me in the right direction as I can't seem to find it thanks.

Pretty much as the title says how many else if statements are you allowed? I have this contact form that spits out an error if someone using anything other than letters in the name and subject field.

When I remove the preg_match for my subject field so they can put anything they want it works fine but when I add it back in even when they use only letters it still says 'Subject field must only contain letters', I have a feeling it is because you're only allowed one else if statement. If this is the case how would I go about showing the error_subject message for the subject field and error_name for the name field?

I appreciate any bit of help :) Thanks

PHP Contact Form Code:

```
    <?php

  //Response Generation Function
  $response = "";

  //Function To Generate Response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "
      <div class='success-message'>
        <div class='success'>{$message}</div>
      </div>";
    else $response = "
      <div class='error-message'>
        <div class='error'>{$message}</div>
      </div>";

  }

  //Response Message
  $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
  $missing_content = "Please fill in all required fields.";
  $error_name = "Full Name field must only contain letters";
  $error_subject = "Subject field must only contain letters";
  $email_invalid   = "E-Mail Address Invalid.";
  $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
  $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

  //User Posted Variable
  $name = $_POST['message_name'];
  $email = $_POST['message_email'];
  $tele = $_POST['message_tele'];
  $subject = $_POST['message_subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message_text'];
  $human = $_POST['message_human'];

  //PHP Mailer Variables
  $to = 'stephen@e-foreknowledge.co.uk';
  $subject = "New Message - ".get_bloginfo('name');
  $headers = "From: $email\n\n";  
  $body = 
  "Name: $name\n\n Subject: $subject\n\n Telephone: $tele\n\n Message: $message\n";

  if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

      //Validate Email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //Email is Valid
      {
        //Validate Presence of Name and Message
        if(empty($name) || empty($tele) || empty($subject) || empty($message)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        } 
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $error_name);
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $subject)) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $error_subject);
        }                 
        else {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $headers, $body);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //Message Sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //Mssage Wasn't Sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
```

This is for my WordPress site, I'm making a custom contact page with a contact form inside. The answer is below if you have the same problem I was having :)

Comment: Don't set variables before using `isset` otherwise you'll probably get *undefined index error*.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I'm not advanced in PHP really or have much knowledge I was looking at a tutorial while writing this PHP code, sorry for my noobiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is I was calling the $subject in two different place that meant two different things and they clashed. I was using one for the subject that is shown within an E-Mail and the other was for the subject field on the contact page. The fixed code is below :)

```
<?php

  //Response Generation Function
  $response = "";

  //Function To Generate Response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "
      <div class='success-message'>
        <div class='success'>{$message}</div>
      </div>";
    else $response = "
      <div class='error-message'>
        <div class='error'>{$message}</div>
      </div>";

  }

  //Response Message
  $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
  $missing_content = "Please fill in all required fields.";
  $error_name = "Full Name field must only contain letters";
  $error_subject = "Subject field must only contain letters";
  $email_invalid   = "E-Mail Address Invalid.";
  $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
  $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

  //User Posted Variable
  $name = $_POST['message_name'];
  $email = $_POST['message_email'];
  $tele = $_POST['message_tele'];
  $formsubj = $_POST['message_subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message_text'];
  $human = $_POST['message_human'];

  //PHP Mailer Variables
  $to = 'stephen@e-foreknowledge.co.uk';
  $subject = "New Message - ".get_bloginfo('name');
  $headers = "From: $email\n\n";  
  $body = 
  "Name: $name\n\n Subject: $formsubj\n\n Telephone: $tele\n\n Message: $message\n";

  if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

      //Validate Email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //Email is Valid
      {
        //Validate Presence of Name and Message
        if(empty($name) || empty($tele) || empty($formsubj) || empty($message)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        } 
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $error_name);
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $formsubj)) {
            my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $error_subject);
        }                 
        else {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $headers, $body);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //Message Sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //Mssage Wasn't Sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As many as you want. There is no limit on any programming construct in any language. The limit is disk space and memory usage.

Your problem is here:

```
$subject = "New Message - ".get_bloginfo('name');
```

you actually insert a hyphen (`-`) in the subject yourself.

Comment: Hmmm.. how would I run into the error that I am running into? It works for the name field it's just as soon as I remove the subject perg_match it works but when I add it back in it breaks and doesn't send the E-Mail

Comment: Ah, I think I just found the answer from the information you gave me. You see I'm using WordPress and this is my code for the custom contact page BUT where my $subject = "New Message - ".get_bloginfo('name'); is that is there so when the message is sent in your inbox the title you see is WordPress and underneath the Subject which is New Message - (Website Name) and I think that was clashing with my custom Subject Field in my form field. I then changed the $subject = $_POST['message_subject']; to $formsubj and now that works. Thanks for your help Bart :)